# Windows phone 8 SDK install issue

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to install Windows phone 8 SDK on a Windows 8 Box.
It installs but windows never boot again stuck on the blue windows logo forever.
The only way to make it boot is to restore before the wp8 sdk installation

Did someone runned into this issue?
Can I obtain some log about the booting of windows?

Here is my environnement:

- Physical system
- Windows 8 Professional 64bits French with french locale
- Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate
- VmWare workstation 9 installed (can it conflict with hyperv?)
- Intel core i5 2500k CPU with 8Go of ram

Comment: Uninstalling VMWare 9 didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.
My mother board is a Z68XP-UD3 from gigabyte.
You can boot into windows after installing WP8SDK (or Hyper-v i think) with **disabling all USB3.0 controllers** into the Bios.

Disabling Virtualization technologies solve the issue without disabling USB3.0 but i need it for the WP8 SDK

Answer (score 1):

> VmWare workstation 9 installed (can it conflict with hyperv?)

Yes. And that's most likely your problem. Please try without VMWare (or any other virtualization software) installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its VMWare, I actually had to turn off Hyper-V to run VMWare Player, make sure you also have  Second Level Address Translation 'SLAT' enabled on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have VMWare working on a machine that will also have HYPER-V enabled. That will cause you problems. I recommend that you move your VMWare machines to HYPER-V and use HYPER-V as the only visualization solution on your machine.